# A Book About a Maid murdered in the attic

Tags: story-identification, novel

Back when I was in middle school, I remember reading a lot of Christopher Pike novels and I remember reading a book by its cover. It had a sword and some weird creature hidden in the darkness that looked like an octopus and it was a red book with black on it.

Basically at least 5 or 6 kids enter a haunted house and the stories is that a maid girl was murdered in the house by one of the family members, more pointing to the man of the house. The two had had an affair and the wife killed the maid by cutting off her head where she lived in the attic. These kids go into the house, but soon realize it's not a normal house and that they have to get out of the house before sunrise or their lives depend on it. As they will die with the house and they will die with the house during this the board game. They soon become possessed by the demons of the games trying to gain control of their bodies and they want to live with their bodies and go out into the world and wreak havoc. One person finds an octopus looking thing underneath the basement guarding a sword another part where they open the door look out of the window and see Desert, another girl who has the power to freeze. Eventually, though, the house starts to burn down and the creature gets burned, but released home and everybody makes it out alive.

I guess another part is that the night before they were home playing board games and someone could hear voices everyone who got possessed started hearing voices and feeling the power in their body like the feeling sensation of your spine as somebody is trying to enter them. It's similar to Christopher Pike I'm not sure if it is, but I've been looking him up and I don't see anything similar to that story. However, I really love the book and I used to have it, but I lost it so I need help. If anyone knows of the author of the book or what it could possibly be that would help me.

Comment: When were you in middle school?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Story Identification: Young adult novel, horror, teens play a D&D variant, but things start to turn real](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/story-identification-young-adult-novel-horror-teens-play-a-dd-variant-but-t)

Comment: To help confirm the duplicate status, see if either of these covers looks like what you remember: [Cover 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66475677/Spirits%20and%20Spells%201.jpg), [Cover 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66475677/Spirits%20and%20Spells%202.jpg)

Comment: It's considered good form to not vote to close as a duplicate until it's been confirmed (or unless the similarities are blindingly obvious).

Comment: Ah. So noted. I will revert.

Comment: "I remember reading a book by its cover" - don't you know you should NEVER read a book by its cover? ;-))

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/story-identification-young-adult-novel-horror-teens-play-a-dd-variant-but-t/13312#13312/this%20question).

In that case, the accepted answer was :

> ***"SPIRITS AND SPELLS by Bruce Coville, printed in 1984 by Dell
>   Publishing Company as part of their TWILIGHT: WHERE DARKNESS BEGINS
>   series"***

Comment: I'm reading the book now and it's definitely a match.